# Strategy Pattern replacing if/else or case statments

Tags: strategy-pattern

Why does it seem to me that using Strategy is just putting off the if/else to the Factory?
Using Strategy, doesn't a Factory need to figure out which concrete class to instantiate, and doesn't it do so by if/else?

Is another option to use a Map/List somehow, and have the keys be a name of the class to instantiate, and maybe have the class using the Factory pass in a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map\List is an implemetation of Factory pattern.

Using Strategy patter is better than if\else because it's creates les coupled code.
With Factory+Startegy you can extend algorithms of processing without touch of client code, and have more ways to configure code dynamicaly (withot recompile).